# Can not set text on D3

Tags: d3.js

Folks;

I'm trying something that should be basic but coming up empty.  I'm trying to add text to a circle but the text never shows.  The title is showing satisfactorily but the text never appears.  I've tried to set the fill on the circle to none also but still no avail

```
function initializeDisplay() {
    // set the data and properties of link lines
    link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line");

    // set the data and properties of node circles
    node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .style("fill", circleColor)            
            .attr("stroke", "black")    
            .attr("opacity", 50.0)
            .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

    // node tooltip
    node.append("title")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });

    /// text
    node.append("text")
                .attr("dx", -10)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .text("TheText");


    // visualize the graph
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the rendered output, to double check that it's not just a styling issue?

Comment: `text` is not a valid child of `circle`. add circle and text to a `g` element

Comment: Hmmmmm....I expected it to mirror the "title"....so add the text to the g element as defined above this?

Comment: Lissy; I did and the "text" was added to the circle as a peer to "title"

Comment: Lissy:<circle stroke="black" opacity="50" r="15" cx="560.5860349256019" cy="491.7142242926677" style="fill: green;">
   <title>AAA</title>
   <text dx="-10" dy=".35em" fill="black" style="stroke: black;">RJN</text>
</circle>